# convert a string to json format in java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I want to extract data from different blogs. I have done it using article extractor but now I have to convert it into json format for storing into MongoDB. My program is returning entire article as string like this:

```
String news=ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(doc);
```

How can I convert it into json format?

```
     URL url;
       url = new URL("http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/mellowdrama/entry/india-needs-a-law-against-community-crime");
InputSource is = HTMLFetcher.fetch(url).toInputSource();        
       BoilerpipeSAXInput in = new BoilerpipeSAXInput(is);
     TextDocument doc = in.getTextDocument();        
     news=ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(doc);
     System.out.println(news);
     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(news);
```

this last line shows error... the error is

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined

at Article_ext.main(Article_ext.java:39)
```

Comment: You should give more details otherwise it's not possible to format it without knowing what should be stored.

Comment: i gave the details... but still u r saying its nt clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.append("news", news);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try `JSONObject` for conversion of String to Json Format

Try this way:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("Your String");
```

Use [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/)

Comment: which json library you are using?

Comment: json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Comment: use org.json library which you can get it from link.https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Comment: @Kamlesh Arya Thanks a bunch I was also using json-simple-1.1.1.jar based on some early examples I saw of working with json in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the JSON you can use the [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: Because `JSONObject` isn't `formatting` a string to `json` and that even if he succeed into creating a `JSONObject` with the string... how is he going to insert a `JSONObject` into `mongodb` as mongodb uses `BSON` and not `json`. For all I know both answers aren't going to answer anything yet because the question isn't clear.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix i already insert json object into mongodb so hw cn u tel dat its nt possible    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("name", "so").

Comment: @PathuZ because you're not telling us which mongodb driver you're using with Java. You're not saying how you want the data to be saved into the database. For all I know, `"{\"content\": \"" + news + "\"}";` should be enough to save your data because it's json.

Comment: @PathuZ that's what I'm saying. BasicDBObject isn't json, it's building a `BSON` object.